# How to find the application running on a specific port in MAC

Tags: macos, port, devops, netstat

I need to find if there is any application running on port 9000 on my mac.

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo lsof -i :9000
```

-i will list the applications using the mentioned port

Answer (score 1):

In order to find if there is any process running on port 9000, use following command in terminal
`>> netstat -vanp tcp | grep 9000`